# Поиск в запросе по email?

Tags: postgresql

В базе есть колонка email.
Мне нужно в запросе вытаскивать не полный email пользователя, а только то что находится от @ до первой точки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в запросе сделать это условие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуемся регулярным выражением

```
select substring(email from '@(.*?)\.')
  from table
```

Для проверки: `select substring('abc.def@mail.org.ru' from '@(.*?)\.')` возвращает слово `mail`.

Comment: Если не сложно, дайте ссылку на материал который помог Вам разобраться с регулярными выражениями.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Fitstd Сложно. я не помню когда и с чего начинал. в данном примере в принципе азы. когда надо подглядеть что то эдакое, чем редко пользуюсь заглядываю в википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  Когда искал ответ на ваш вопрос просто в гугле вбил 'postges строковые функции' и увидел что substring умеет с регулярками работать. Но диалект у постгреса немного свой, в официальной доке есть

Comment: @Fitstd http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/functions-matching.html